# How can I make my rigidbody rotate to look at my target, is the LookAt() method bugged?

Tags: unity-game-engine

All forms of rigid body rotation cause this issue where my object moves at the target instead of staying still and rotating. I assume this may be due to the rotation colliding with the floor but it has acted oddly in every case I have tried.
This code is in a **FixedUpdate()**
Any ideas what could be going wrong?

[image: Gif in action]
[image: Rigidbody Properties]

Code (*Commented portions were attempted code*):

```
public bool AimAt()
{
    if (target != null) // && IsUpright) todo: fix
    {
        var direction = target.position - transform.position;
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        body.MoveRotation(rotation);
        //transform.LookAt(target);
        //Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.forward, target.position) * transform.rotation;
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The rotate center is not on the ground and there is gravity, so the cube will be pushed forward a bit by friction every frame you rotate it. I think the it will stay if you remove the plane and gravity.

Comment: Two options: 1) Set `direction.y = 0`, keep the cube on the ground. 2) Lift the cube `body.MovePosition` before rotate it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a script on your object that moves it towards the target?

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya Positive. I've removed all scripts prior and it's just this in an update/fixed update.

Comment: @shingo ok, I'll try a few attempts of this. Is this the standard for rigidbody rotation if you know? Weird it would not be in docs and other examples I've seen.

Comment: I think what you did is not common, we won't rotate a cube in this way.